# Problem in understanding graphs by trained model

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

h I am learning Machine Learning. I trained 2 classes on 3x layer CNN. The result i got:

```
Epoch 50/50

46/46 [==============================] - 209s 5s/step - loss: 0.3725 - accuracy: 0.8489 - val_loss: 0.3060 - val_accuracy: 0.8000
```

Sir i tried to plot through history and got these two graphs can someone explain me what the graphs explains and If there is a problem what should i do to minimize it. Thank You.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


print(history.history.keys())
# summarize history for accuracy
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
# summarize history for loss
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is showing you the evolution graphs of the model.

During training a portion of the training data is reserved for validation. This means that when each epoch is trained, the state of the model is evaluated with the reserved validation data. Therefore, both graphs show the values ​​obtained in acc and in loss.

A priori it seems that the training has not been enough since none of the curves seems to flatten when it reaches 50 epochs. One option is to increase the number of epochs. Another is to make the model reach the "optimal solution" faster, for this you could use a more powerful optimizer such as ADAM or RMSprop.

Comment: Sir, Thank you for guiding. Sir i am already using ADAM. Sir i want to know why  the model looks not well trained when it has already achieved 80% accuracy. Sir, can you please explain what model loss is showing.

Comment: @MirzaMunib  You mean the acc obtained with the test set, right?
You can try increasing the number of epochs from 50 to 100 to see if it improves.
If you indicate the type of data you are handling, I can try to help you better.

Comment: Sir i have a dataset of macrscopic wood specie. It consist of 1000 per specie images.

Comment: And what is the exact architecture of the model that you are training? And the features of the data?

Comment: Sir, can you send me your email or other social site link so we can talk there i can send you pics of it